# HDF5: updating a cell in a table of integers

Tags: c, hdf5

**Note**: cross posted at http://mail.lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2014-July/007960.html

Using hdf5, I built a `5x4` table. Each cell of the table contains `3 integers`
I'm trying to write a function **setyx** that would update a cell of the table at `y,x`
Here is the C code  I wrote so far.

```
#include "hdf5.h"

/** set 3 'int' values at y/x */
static void setyx(hid_t dataset, hid_t dataspace,
                  int y,int x,
                  int i1,int i2,int i3)
    {
    int values[3]={i1,i2,i3};
    hsize_t  starts[3]={y,x,0};
    hsize_t  counts[3]={1,1,1};
    hsize_t  dims_memory[3]={1,1,3};

    H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace, H5S_SELECT_SET, starts, NULL,  counts, NULL);
    hid_t filespace = H5Dget_space(dataset);
    hid_t  memspace  = H5Screate_simple(3, dims_memory, NULL); 

    H5Dwrite(dataset,
        H5T_NATIVE_INT,
        memspace,
        filespace,
        H5P_DEFAULT,
        values);

     H5Sclose(memspace);
     H5Sclose(filespace);
    }


int main (void)
     {
     hid_t       file, dataset; 
     hid_t       dataspace; 
     hsize_t     dims[3]={5,4,3};


     file = H5Fcreate("test.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
     dataspace = H5Screate_simple(3, dims, NULL);
     dataset = H5Dcreate(file, "/test", H5T_NATIVE_INT, dataspace,
                        H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
     setyx(dataset,dataspace,2,1, 100,200,300);

     H5Sclose(dataspace);
     H5Dclose(dataset);
     H5Fclose(file);
     return 0;
    }
```

but it raises some errors:

```
  #000: H5Dio.c line 225 in H5Dwrite(): can't prepare for writing data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #001: H5Dio.c line 347 in H5D__pre_write(): can't write data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #002: H5Dio.c line 685 in H5D__write(): src and dest data spaces have different sizes
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Bad value
```

what is the correct way to update a given cell at `(y,x)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question was answered on the HDF5 mailing list: http://mail.lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2014-July/007966.html

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hdf5.h"

#define VERIFY(a) do { if((a)<0) { fprintf(stderr,"Failure line %d.\n",__LINE__); exit(-1);}}while(0)

/** set 3 'int' values at y/x */
static void setyx(hid_t dataset, hid_t dataspace,int y,int x,int i1,int i2,int i3)
    {
    int values[3]={i1,i2,i3};
    hsize_t  starts[3]={y,x,0};
    hsize_t  counts[3]={1,1,3};

    hsize_t  dims_memory[3]={1,1,3};



    hid_t filespace = H5Dget_space(dataset);
    hid_t  memspace  = H5Screate_simple(3, dims_memory, NULL); 
    VERIFY(memspace);

    VERIFY(H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace,
            H5S_SELECT_SET,
            starts, NULL, 
            counts, NULL));

    VERIFY(H5Dwrite(dataset,
        H5T_NATIVE_INT,
        memspace,
        dataspace,
        H5P_DEFAULT,
        values));

     H5Sclose(memspace);
     H5Sclose(filespace);
    }


int main (void)
     {
     hid_t       file, dataset; 
     hid_t       dataspace; 
     hsize_t     dims[3]={5,4,3};


     file = H5Fcreate("test.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
     dataspace = H5Screate_simple(3, dims, NULL);
     dataset = H5Dcreate(file, "/test", H5T_NATIVE_INT, dataspace,
                        H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
     setyx(dataset,dataspace,2,1, 100,200,300);

     H5Sclose(dataspace);
     H5Dclose(dataset);
     H5Fclose(file);
     return 0;
    }
```